# extracting file data with lua

Tags: arrays, function, search, lua

here's what i've been trying to do with lua.

i have a ton of pictures i transfer back and forth between 2+ computers. I always end up having multiple copies of pictures. I would like my lua code to get all the file names from the folder and allow me to input a search filter (a file name) that the program will compare to the list of file names and let me know if it's already in the folder or not. I've been racking my brain for the past few days to get this to work but no luck, all i've got so far is the text box made and i can get lua to return data about the files in the folder with this:

```
local f = io.popen("dir \"C:\\mydir\\\"")
if f then
    print(f:read("*a"))
else
    print("failed to read")
end
```

Comment: why wouldn't you consider a tool already built designed to keep folders sync'd? for example, dropbox would probably do exactly what you need here...

Answer (score 3):

Standard Lua has no mechanism for doing what you want. It's a scripting language designed for embedded systems, unlike Python which has a massive, feature-rich runtime library.

If you want to do this, you should consider using [the Lua FileSystem module](http://keplerproject.github.com/luafilesystem/index.html). It can get directory lists and that sort of thing.

Comment: ok ill check it out, although i don't know a lot about lua but i know even less about filesystem module lol

Comment: @Jason  I would recommend looking at the filesystem module as it will allow you to check filesizes update dates etc easily. I also use the MD5 module to compare files.  There is an example of reading a directory tree using it here: http://www.fhug.org.uk/wiki/doku.php?id=plugins:code_snippets:directory_tree

Comment: The best solution is indeed LFS. I prefer the API offered by the Penlight library (http://stevedonovan.github.com/Penlight/ - see pl.path and pl.dir) which depends on LFS.

Answer (score 1):

How to get an array of filenames from some folder:

```
local function get_files(path, prepend_path_to_filenames)
   if path:sub(-1) ~= '\\' then
      path = path..'\\'
   end
   local pipe = io.popen('dir /b/a-d "'..path..'*.*" 2> nul')
   local output = pipe:read'*a'
   pipe:close()
   -- If your file names contain national characters
   -- output = convert_OEM_to_ANSI(output)
   local files = {}
   for filename in output:gmatch'[^\r\n]+' do
      if prepend_path_to_filenames then
         filename = path..filename
      end
      table.insert(files, filename)
   end
   return files
end

local array_of_files = get_files('C:\\mydir', false)
for _, fn in ipairs(array_of_files) do
   print(fn)
end
```

Empty array will be returned in case of path not exists (no distinction between empty folder and non-existing folder).